# During junior year, should I focus on taking advanced courses in my major for admission to grad school, or can I take courses for my minor?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I came in as a liberal arts major freshman year, and by around February realized it wasn't what I wanted to do.

I took general chemistry last summer. By the end of the summer, I had begun working in a research lab and was already on track to graduate with the rest of my fellow biochem majors. By that I mean I was in the same courses as everyone else, 
 e.g., took organic, physics, required maths, etc.

This summer I'll be working a paid internship working in the lab, and might be able to get something published. Junior year will be this fall; I'm taking biochemistry and physical chemistry. In that regard, I'm on track with the other chem majors.

I'm not sure to what extent this is a "problem" per se, but I've really begun to enjoy physics and decided to minor it after the introductory physics courses I took this year. I was considering taking two higher-level physics courses both in the fall and spring of my junior year.

I want to go graduate school for chemistry. But will it look bad on my transcript if I have all of those physics courses junior year? That is, will it seem like I'm not focused enough in the field of chemistry? Should I be spending those seven credit hours on something like analytical chem or a special topic in biochemistry course instead? Should my junior year have more chemistry courses than biochem and pchem? Should I drop the physics courses to focus on more chemistry courses?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you've got a plan to take all of the courses required for your chemistry core. That being the case, having a physics minor won't hurt you since physics and chemistry are closely related sciences. Having a broader background in a related science will likely help you as long as you have the required core courses. You will also have a chance to do some more upper level chemistry work in your senior year.

Doing research will really stand out in your application as well, and this is at least as good as having done an upper division special topics course. Since graduate school is more focused on research, having undergraduate research experience lines up well with your plans, and that will stand out to the selection committee.

My one suggestion would be to start looking ahead to where you want to go to grad school. Look at their graduate college page and see what courses are required for applicants and make sure your remaining course work lines up with that. Also look at the faculty research pages and start thinking about who you want to work with as a graduate adviser (a critical decision!). Contact a couple you're interested in and ask for a phone or skype informational interview. In addition, talk to your current research adviser or the principal investigator you're going to be working with this summer. Most likely, they will be very happy to mentor you in preparing for graduate school, and also helping you establish contacts at your schools of interest. My undergraduate research advisor helped me open doors to both graduate school and a prestigious post-grad internship that really boosted my appeal as a grad school candidate. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you're applying for graduate school programs, you want to present the strongest case you can that you are on track to satisfy the requirements of the program and, even more importantly, that you will be able to do research in the field. Most undergraduate chemistry departments have a relatively well-specified curriculum, with a number of courses being fairly standard requirements (general, organic, physical, inorganic, analytical), and then a few electives. If possible, if you can, you should try to have all the "standard" courses and one or two of the more advanced electives finished by the time you apply.

The extra courses in physics might be helpful, but not nearly so much as the chemistry courses will be. So, if you have to choose between a chemistry course and a physics course, I'd go with the chemistry course this year, and wait until your senior year to take the remaining ones.

Comment: You see, under normal circumstances I'd do this, but the class is only offered on odd years, and it's a really interesting course on gravitation and spacetime that I won't get to take unless I do it my junior year. At the same time, that's four credit hours I could be spending on some specialized biochemistry course

Comment: You said you wanted to take multiple courses in physics, so you could always split the difference.

Comment: Right, the issue is that if I don't take those specific courses this year, they won't be offered the next year, my senior year, as they're only offered in the spring of odd years (2019)

Comment: Given that, I’d argue do one of each: take an advanced chem course and an advanced physics course. Unfortunately, sometimes we have to think of long-term goals in making short-term decisions and sacrifice. Besides, you might be able to incorporate some of your physics work into your graduate curriculum, as many grad programs require a minor as well.